# Two Table Views In Different View Controllers one working and one not(Swift 4)

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swift4, xcode11

I'm aiming to build an app where there are two lists in two different views 1 is called Shopping List and the second pantry list. This is in a tabbed application template. I first set up the shopping list tab with a view containing a table view which gets its data to fill the view from a common variable file and this works fine. However, I copied and pasted the same code into the second view controller(Changing all the variables and references INCLUDING the @IBOutlet Link) and this tab shows only an empty table view.

**Shopping list Tab View Controller**

```
class ShoppingListTabViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var ShoppingListTableView: UITableView!

//Set the # of rows in the shopping List
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { //Set the # of rows
    return(Common.Global.shoppingList.count)
}

//Define what a cell looks like
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //Create a cell with the default style and the id of the Table in the Shopping List tab
    let shoppinglistItem = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "shoppingListCell")
    shoppinglistItem.textLabel?.text = Common.Global.shoppingList[indexPath.row] //Fill the table with the items from the  shoppingList
    return(shoppinglistItem)

}
```

}

**Pantry List Tab View Controller**

```
class PantryListTabViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var PantryListTableView: UITableView!

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //Set the number of rows in table
    return(Common.Global.pantryItems.count)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //Setup the cell which each item will be stored in
    let pantryItemsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PantryListItem", for: indexPath)

    pantryItemsCell.textLabel!.text = Common.Global.pantryItems[indexPath.row]
    return(pantryItemsCell)
}
```

}

They both reference the same Common file which contains two lists one called ShoppingList and the other pantry items

I'm sorry if I stuffed up asking the question.

Comment: have you ensure your datasource has content and set properly? Both in your code and in your storyboard?

Comment: That fixed it thanks so much your amazing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class `PantryListTabViewController` is already conforming to **both TableView Protocols** (`UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`)

> These **protocols** tell other classes that this class (`PantryListTabViewController`) has **implemented** some specific methods or properties

However, the **TableView needs to know**, that this class (`PantryListTabViewController`) is the class the **TableView should use to populate it's content** and some other things.

> Therefore, in your `viewDidLoad()`, you need to set up your class as the **Delegate and DataSource** for the TableView:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {

    // Call the super method.
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Setup Delegate and DataSource for the TableView.
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}
```

Please consider that you need an `IBOutlet` of your `TableView` called tableView (you can obviously rename it)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue you need to make sure that your Datasource and delegate is set properly for both view controllers you do this by adding:

```
mytableview@IBOutletvar.delegate = self
mytableview@IBOutletvar.dataSource = self
```

to both view controllers viewDidLoad() function.

In my case mytableview@IBOutletvar = ShoppingListTableView for the shopping list view controller and PantryListTableView for the pantry list view controller.